# Is my team's FT% improving/increasing over time?

Tags: statistical-significance

I figured that the only way to get statistical significance is to do a rolling average. I don't know a lot about stats but I believe that 1 sample size of 100ish Takes makes these stats +/- 9%? How can I tell whether we're improving over time? Should i perform a statistical regression instead? I don't know which calculation to use?

I added the team stats below:

[image: Team's FT % over time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is some sort of free throw percentage.

Let's plot the data

[image]

It isn't enough to just look at the plots.  Dates which have more free throws have a more precise estimate of the FT% than dates which have fewer free throws.  You can use a variety of models for data like these.  I'm going to keep it simple and plot a regression weighting each observation of the FT% by the number of observations on that date.  The trend is shown below

[image]

It may look like your FT% is increasing, but the slope of this line is not statistically distinguishable from no increase in FT% as a function of time.  Shown below is the model output

```
Call:
lm(formula = (makes/takes) ~ t, data = d, weights = takes)

Weighted Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.7292 -0.2650 -0.1260  0.2557  1.1678 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.594751   0.044380  13.401 8.36e-11
t           0.001003   0.001142   0.878    0.391
               

---
Signif. codes:  
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

You want to focus your attention on the row labelled `t` (for time since the first date listed).  The coefficient is estimated to be positive, but there is a relatively large uncertainty (relative to the estimate of the effect), meaning the effect could be positive *or* negative, we can't say for certain.  All in all, you could not conclude from these data alone that your FT% is increasing.